# How to replace Lucene query Filter

Tags: java, lucene

I'm new to Lucene and I'm trying to understand [this doc](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/techniques/permission-filtering.html) about managing permissions via filters.

From what I understand, in the now-deprecated Filter interface one could check the int IDs returned by a query (using Bits acceptDocs) and return a new Bits object, containing only the IDs of documents authorised.

The Filter class was removed from 6.x and the [documentation from 5.x](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Filter.html) says:

*Use Query objects instead: when queries are wrapped in a ConstantScoreQuery or in a BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER clause, they automatically disable the score computation so the Filter class does not provide benefits compared to queries anymore.*

I really can't understand how. I realise I should use the boolean query builder and the FILTER Occur option, but I can't understand how to implement the same filtering behaviour, which gets documents being returned by the underlining query and tells if they can actually be returned or not.

Comment: I think the idea is to use ordinary query as a boolean clause with Filter occur option, which will do the trick for filtering.

Comment: Sure, but how? How can I build a filter criterion, which examine documents being returned by an underlining query, and fit it into a boolean clause?

Comment: I will provide an answer to you, could you describe use case, what filter criterion will look like to you?

Comment: Thank you, @Mysterion. I'm just learning, but for simplicity, suppose I have a set of document IDs that are denied to the current user and I don't want to show. The filter would go through all the docs returned by the base query and filter out those in the denied set.

Comment: I know this post is almost 5 years old, but has anyone here come up with a solution or prototype for how to replace Lucene Filter and FilteredQuery from Lucene 5 with Boolean queries? I'm still unclear how to implement this specifically, or even what the migration guide here is suggesting: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_5_1/MIGRATE.html